# access to .swf API

Tags: api, flash, introspection

Given a `.swf` file, is there a way to *inspect* the API provided?

I have a FLASH .swf file on a web-page that plays .mp3 and I'd like to control playback through a Google Chrome extension but it seems I can't find documentation on their API.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML source code of the webpage hosting the `.swf`? If the webpage has an ability to control the `.swf`, maybe you can find a script (e.g. Javascript) that controls it.

Comment: @In silico: yes I have done that to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the various Flash decompilers (for example, [this one](http://www.flash-decompiler.com/)) to look inside the ActionScript code and see if it exposes any methods. If the player is using a recent enough version of Flash, you should look for references to [ExternalInterface](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) because that's the main way to expose things to JavaScript etc.